# Проблема с Joom-ой или моими руками)

Tags: php, sql, joomla

Не могу понять в чем проблема, убил уже часов 8. Суть проблемы:
Написал небольшой компонент для джумлы(Пока пустой, задача - создать таблицу в БД).

Вот код запроса:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__news` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    `published` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `text` text NOT NULL,
    `images` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `publish_up` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `alias` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

В ответ получаю:

> JInstaller:: Install: Ошибка SQL У вас есть ошибка в синтаксисе SQL;
>   Проверьте руководство, соответствующее версии сервера MariaDB, для
>   правильного синтаксиса, используемого рядом с 'CREATE TABLE, если не
>   EXISTS `#__ news` (`id` int (11) unsigned NOT NUL' в строке 1
>   Extension Install: запрос обработки ошибок SQL: ошибка функции DB с
>   номером ошибки 1064  У вас есть ошибка в синтаксисе SQL; Проверьте
>   руководство, соответствующее вашей версии сервера MariaDB, для
>   правильного синтаксиса, используемого рядом с 'CREATE TABLE, если не
>   EXISTS `#__ news` (`id` int (11) unsigned NOT NUL' в строке 1

Но если, написать в консоле phpmyadmin, все отлично создает... 
Версии:

- Joomla 3.7.3 (Скачано с Joomla.org)
- php 7.1.1.
- MySql 5.0
  Может, чего еще не написал...

Answer (score 0):

Решения проблемы в смене кодировки!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]